# Apache TomEE and Tomcat co-existence on Windows systems

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee

Is it possible to have apache tomcat and apachetomee-plus on an windows machine together.
Since while setting up Tomcat6; I had setup CATALINA_HOME environment variable; I think when apache tomee starts up [using the startup.bat file included in the TomEE distribution] it picks up the CATALINA_HOME variable of the Tomcat setup.

Can we have both these servers in an windows (or other systems) and make sure when I start the startp.bat of TomEE plus server my Tomcat Servlet container does not get picked up?

```
System Info:
Windows 7 64 bit
JAVA 1.6.0_21
TomEE: apache-tomee-plus-1.5.1
Tomcat: 6.0
```

Thanks,

Ayusman

Answer (score 1):

you can set CATALINA_* variable in the starting scripts instead of windows env variables. It should do the trick.

Comment: I had the same view, but this will cause the script of TOMEE to be changed. Which I wanted to avoid.